# I need help with comma usage

Tags: commas

I am trying to say that I chose to make an explanation video and that I annotated a copy of the file. But something seems odd about the sentence below. Should there be a comma after video, and then something different about what comes after? I feel like the word annotate is throwing me off, because if it wasn't there and I was simply making a copy of the file, then the sentence would be fine.

"That is why I have chosen to make the explanation video and annotate a copy of the file."

Comment: I'd have added "to", but the sentence is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a comma.  You have two infinitive phrases as objects of the verb.  You could emphasize the parallel structure by putting 'to' in front of 'annotate'.